# Using X11::GUITest on a modern mac

Tags: macos, perl, x11, www-mechanize-firefox, xquartz

I'd like to use the [`X11::GUITest`](http://search.cpan.org/~ctrondlp/X11-GUITest-0.28/GUITest.pm) perl module to control my browser in conjunction with the [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.79/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm) module on my Mac running High Sierra.

I downloaded and installed [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org/). I'm not sure what to do next get this to work. When I try:

```
use X11::GUITest qw(SendKeys FindWindowLike ClickWindow SetEventSendDelay QuoteStringForSendKeys);
```

I get:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _XOpenDisplay
  Referenced from: /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/darwin-2level/auto/X11/GUITest/GUITest.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _XOpenDisplay
  Referenced from: /Users/me/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/lib/site_perl/5.24.1/darwin-2level/auto/X11/GUITest/GUITest.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

Abort trap: 6
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?